# Does anyone know of any example C16x code that vasm will assemble?

Tags: assembly, syntax

I recently found out that [vasm](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/) exists, is open source, and supports the C16x/ST10 architecture. I have a [project](https://github.com/flarn2006/BHSTools/) on Github for modding a C161PI-based embedded device, and it currently uses the proprietary Keil assembler, as I was unaware an open source one existed. For multiple reasons, I'd like to convert this over to use vasm, but though it supports four different types of syntax, none of them work as a drop-in replacement for Keil; I figure I'm going to need to reformat the code to something vasm can parse.

I'm having trouble getting it to read some common instructions though; for instance, jumps. Does anyone know of any example code they can point me to which `vasmc16x` will assemble? Preferably for all four syntax types (`std`, `oldstyle`, `madmac` and `mot`) but even for just one would be helpful. I don't see any in the [documentation](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/release/vasm.html) for the c16x module. It does document the syntax modules separately, but I'm looking for C16x-specific syntax.

Comment: I know you didn't ask this, but since you mentioned open source ... are you aware that the GNU assembler also exists? It can assemble your `BHSTools/bsl/a66src/dynexec.a66` file with minor modifications. Cropped to lines 8-19 which is the code, and replaced `h` suffix with `0x` prefix for hex numbers.

Comment: @Jester Wait really? All I see about that online is this old GCC toolchain that's no longer available, not even archived anywhere I can find. But I don't think that one was open source (even though they were legally required to.) Got a link? (Also, do you know of any open-source C166 emulators?)

Comment: It's the stock binutils. Support has been [added in 2006](http://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=d70c5fc7c56fa9915f594aca8de15b478f3ab5b0)

Comment: @Jester That's interesting; I use Arch (as the meme goes) and typing `man as` shows a whole bunch of different architectures but `/[Cc]16` (searches for "c16" or "C16") doesn't find anything. Is it supported but they just forgot to document it or something?

Comment: The man page only lists target specific options. If a target doesn't have such (and c16 doesn't) it's not mentioned. At least my debian man page doesn't have an "all supported architectures" list.

Comment: @Jester Got it working; thanks! :D Like I said about vasm, I wish I had known about this `2B xx` ;)

Comment: @Jester How do I define additional 8-bit registers? Like T3CON (among many others) on the C161PI. Is there a directive I can use for this, or do I need to edit the source code and compile it into the assembler? Where's the documentation for this?

Comment: I am not really familiar with C16. Maybe you can just define a macro if the instructions otherwise accept a register number.